# Code review Check-in policy for Visual Studio Online

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, checkin, azure-devops, checkin-policy

Is there a OOB Code review policy on check in for **TFS online**

i took a look at http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3bd2115e-9009-414b-bb5b-a0a64e4dad9e/view/Discussions
but this seems to be for tfs 2013 on prem.

If not, ca someone point me towards implementing a custom check in policy

As pointed, the tool works for TFS online, but has to be installed on every box, which would be connecting to the TFS online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think it only is for TFS on prem? Did you try it out? Seems like I can configure it for TFS online.

Comment: And you are absolutely correct. Will test this with another developer working on the same application